# cannot send string from one frame to another

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets

I have been trying to create a chat program for end to end message transmission between frames in a computer. But somehow its not working. No error or warning. I have been scratching my head over this for about 2 hours. The User interface and other components are working perfectly and i couldn't find any answer in internet. 
There is a client script.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ChatClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener,FocusListener{
  JButton button;
  JLabel label;
  JTextField text;
  Socket socket;
  String hostname = "localhost";
  final int portno = 3000;
  PrintWriter out;
  BufferedReader bin;
  int y=10;
  String defaultMessage = "Enter your message..";
  public ChatClient(){
    try{
      makeUI();
      socket = new Socket(hostname,portno);
      out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
      bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      new ClientThread().start();
    }catch(Exception ae){
      System.out.println("Error! --> "+ae.getMessage());
    }
  }
  public void makeUI(){
    setTitle("FIreFly-Client");
    text = new JTextField(defaultMessage);
    text.setBounds(10,620,295,40);
    text.addFocusListener(this);
    add(text);
    button = new JButton("SEND");
    button.setBounds(310,620,80,40);
    button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    button.setBackground(Color.decode("#11A458"));
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    add(button);
    setSize(400,700);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent ae){
    if(text.getText().equals(defaultMessage)){
        text.setText("");
    }
  }
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent ae){
    if(text.getText().isEmpty()){
      text.setText(defaultMessage);
    }
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if(!text.getText().isEmpty()){
      if(!text.getText().equals(defaultMessage)){
        out.println(text.getText());
        label = new JLabel(text.getText());
        label.setBounds(10,y,380,20);
        y = y+20;
        add(label);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String []args){
    try{
        new ChatClient();
    }catch(Exception ae){
      System.out.println("Error! --> "+ae.getMessage());
    }
  }
  class ClientThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
      String receive;
      try{
        while(true){
          receive = bin.readLine();
          if(!receive.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(receive);
            label = new JLabel(receive);
            label.setBounds(10,y,380,20);
            y = y+20;
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            add(label);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
          }
        }
      }catch(Exception ae){
        ae.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the server part of the program looks like,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ChatServer extends JFrame implements ActionListener,FocusListener{
  JButton button;
  JLabel label;
  JTextField text;
  Socket socket;
  ServerSocket ss;
  String hostname = "localhost";
  final int portno = 3000;
  PrintWriter out;
  BufferedReader bin;
  int y=10;
  String defaultMessage = "Enter your message..";
  public ChatServer(){
    try{
      makeUI();
      ss = new ServerSocket(portno);
      socket = ss.accept();
      out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
      bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      new ServerThread().start();
    }catch(Exception ae){
      System.out.println("Error! --> "+ae.getMessage());
    }
  }
  public void makeUI(){
    setTitle("FireFly-Server");
    text = new JTextField(defaultMessage);
    text.setBounds(10,620,295,40);
    text.addFocusListener(this);
    add(text);
    button = new JButton("SEND");
    button.setBounds(310,620,80,40);
    button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    button.setBackground(Color.decode("#11A458"));
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    add(button);
    setSize(400,700);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent ae){
    if(text.getText().equals(defaultMessage)){
        text.setText("");
    }
  }
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent ae){
    if(text.getText().isEmpty()){
      text.setText(defaultMessage);
    }
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if(!text.getText().isEmpty()){
      if(!text.getText().equals(defaultMessage)){
        System.out.println(text.getText());
        out.println(text.getText());
        label = new JLabel(text.getText());
        label.setBounds(10,y,380,20);
        y = y+20;
        add(label);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String []args){
    try{
        new ChatServer();
    }catch(Exception ae){
      System.out.println("Error! --> "+ae.getMessage());
    }
  }
  class ServerThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
      String receive;
      try{
        while(true){
          receive = bin.readLine();
          if(!receive.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(receive);
            label = new JLabel(receive);
            label.setBounds(10,y,380,20);
            y = y+20;
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            add(label);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
          }
        }
      }catch(Exception ae){
        ae.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: What happens when you debug this? Where is the problem occurring? Are the Strings being transferred but not displayed? Your GUI has threading issues, to be sure, but don't know if that is causing your code to fail.

Comment: What threading issues?

Comment: The strings are not being transferred.

Comment: Gabor shows you the issues -- you're making changes to the Swing GUI off of the event thread, although this is not the cause of your problems. You need to do more in-dept debugging, and should do this before coming here.

Comment: Myself, I'd not add JLabels but rather would display the text using a JList.

Comment: I did a lot of debugging and i cant find the problem. That why i  asked the question here.

Comment: You're not flushing your output stream after writing, that's your problem.

Comment: JList is better. This program is not for any use. I am trying to study java.

Comment: I do not see where anything is sent/written into the socket output stream, neither on server nor on client side

Comment: @Heri: it's there in the actionPerformed methods -- `out.println(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the output stream after calling println, else it sits in the output stream buffer and is never sent.

```
out.println(text.getText());
out.flush(); // add this
```

add the flush to both programs.

A client gui could look something like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChatClient2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int VIS_ROW_CNT = 25;
    private static final String HOST_NAME = "localhost";
    private static final int PORT_NO = 3000;
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<String> jList = new JList<>(listModel);
    private SendAction sendAction = new SendAction("Send");
    private JButton sendButton = new JButton(sendAction);
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    private PrintWriter out;

    public ChatClient2(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        SocketWorker worker = new SocketWorker(socket);
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new WorkerListener());
        worker.execute();

        jList.setPrototypeCellValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        jList.setVisibleRowCount(VIS_ROW_CNT);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        textField.setAction(sendAction);
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        bottomPanel.add(textField);
        bottomPanel.add(sendButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void lineToGui(String line) {
        listModel.addElement(line);
    }

    private class SendAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SendAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = textField.getText();
            if (!text.trim().isEmpty()) {
                out.println(text);
                out.flush();
                lineToGui("Me: " + text);
            }
            textField.selectAll();
            textField.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }

    private class SocketWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
        private BufferedReader bin;

        public SocketWorker(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            bin = new BufferedReader(isr);
        } 

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bin.readLine()) != null) {
                publish(line);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String line : chunks) {
                lineToGui("Server: " + line);
            }
        }
    }

    private class WorkerListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                SwingWorker worker = (SwingWorker) evt.getSource();
                try {
                    worker.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(HOST_NAME, PORT_NO);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(socket));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui(Socket socket) {
        ChatClient2 mainPanel = null;
        try {
            mainPanel = new ChatClient2(socket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChatClient2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The message sent from the client is receiving in the server side. But the messages from server is not getting in client program. And thank you for the help. I missed that step.

Comment: @draner: debug where you're putting the JLabels. Again, use a JList and you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @draner: see edits to show one way the client could be set up using a JList.

Comment: worked after adding a few more lines. Thank you. And i used JLabel because i want to do something else. Like adding a custom border.

Comment: @draner: that can be done by using a JList's custom cell renderer. I avoid using null layouts like the plague as they always come back to haunt me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the EDT (event dispatch thread) to update the UI, something like this:

```
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        label = new JLabel(receive);
        label.setBounds(10,y,380,20);
        y = y+20;
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        add(label);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
      });
```

Both on client and server side. Hope this fixes your problem (though it is strange that this did not cause exceptions).

Comment: Correct but not likely to be the cause of the original poster's problem.

Comment: No. Its not working. The message is not even transferred across the frames.

Comment: @draner in that case you should have reduced the problem to the minimal not working state. I thought you have tested and it was working with printlns and things like that. Now it seems like you are before the actual Swing problems.

Comment: I have debugged it using println . But is didnt work. I even tried some local help.